# Input with default value set to 0 is being rendered without the 0

Tags: c#, html, input, default

I have a HTML number input on my page that accepts an integer value. The code is as follows:

```
@Html.TextBox("Answer[" + i + "].Score", null, new { @class = "form-control", type = "number", value="0", id = "Answer[" + i + "]_Score" })
```

In my model I have defaulted all the `Score` properties to 0 but it still didn't render with a 0 in the view. I then used `value="0"` directly on the input but it still doesn't render the 0.

It renders like:

```
<input class="form-control" id="Answer[0]_Score" name="Answer[0].Score" type="number" value="">
```

This is only a problem when I go to save the form, a null value is sent to the controller when score isn't nullable so the form doesn't submit.

Is there any way to get that 0 to be the default instead of a blank value?

Comment: use 0 without quotes. Since this is a `type=number` you are passing it a string `"0"` and not the value 0. `value=0` (Yvette is correct and I didn't see the answer posted when I commented).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [Value with a capital V](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.defaultvalueattribute.value(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Value = "0"
```

not

```
value="0"
```

`value` is a keyword used in setters. [for example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/value).

```
private int num;
public virtual int Number
{
    get { return num; }
    set { num = value; }
}
```

As you need to set the value of "num" (in this case Answer_++) explicitly in the code behind when you create the object - the value is not set, so it is empty.

So `Value` is not overwritten by the value of the setter.

Also always have error handling and null checks when passing data through controllers.

Comment: This doesn't work a 0 is not posted back. The HTML is still rendered as value instead of value = 0

Comment: Thats the one there! Thanks!

Comment: I didn't downvote you, I saw it go down just before I up voted it up. I dont know why it was downvoted.

Comment: Oh you beat me also on a comment! But not sure why you were downvoted, this is the correct answer.

Comment: It said Ive to wait 3 mins a few mins ago. Ill mark as answer when I can :)

Comment: Also FYI it can work as Value="0"

Comment: It works both ways

Answer (score 2):

Make sure 'v' in the Value is capital. And then use :

```
    Value = "0"
```

Comment: This doesnt work, a 0 is not posted back

Comment: Make sure 'v' in the Value is capital. And then use Value ="0".

Comment: Now it should work

Comment: Yeah the capital V is needed along with wrapping the 0 in quotations. So simple but can catch people out.

Comment: alright Thank you

Comment: That's so kind of you. Thanks :)